# Heroku build failed during gradle task 'nodeSetup' with error 'Couldn't follow symbolic link'

Tags: java, node.js, gradle, heroku

The first time I create an application on heroku, everything works fine, but all subsequent deploys fail during build process during the `nodeSetup` gradle task with this error

```
Failed to capture fingerprint of output files for task ':nodeSetup' property 'nodeDir' during up-to-date check.
       > Could not list contents of '/tmp/build_f8eae163382a61b2896d7be434b4dc58/.gradle/nodejs/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/bin/npm'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.
```

I have to create a new heroku project every time I want to deploy this. So, it only works for the first time. Even if I clear the cache using `./gradlew clean`, it fails during the build because it does not clear the `.gradle` folder

If I SSH into the project and manually run `./gradlew build`, it works without a problem. The error only happens during the heroku build process (of the buildpack)

I am using https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin in order to use webpack for the frontend in the project https://github.com/zhcet-amu/zhcet-web.

I guess similar issues have been encountered by many people. This may be due to caching the directory and trying to access non-existent one on second deploy?

This is the full build log

```
-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Spring Boot detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
-----> executing ./gradlew build -x test
       > Task :bootBuildInfo
       > Task :compileKotlin
       > Task :nodeSetup FAILED

       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

       * What went wrong:
       Failed to capture fingerprint of output files for task ':nodeSetup' property 'nodeDir' during up-to-date check.
       > Could not list contents of '/tmp/build_f8eae163382a61b2896d7be434b4dc58/.gradle/nodejs/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/bin/npm'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.

       * Try:
       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

       * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

       BUILD FAILED in 27s
       3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
 !     ERROR: Failed to run Gradle!
       We're sorry this build is failing. If you can't find the issue in application
       code, please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com
       You can also try reverting to the previous version of the buildpack by running:
       $ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle#previous-version

       Thanks,
       Heroku
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Gradle app.
 !     Push failed
```

Personally, I don't care if anything is cached or not and rebuilding takes longer as currently, deployments don't even work. I'd love to send a PR if guided in the direction of what needs to be done here, but for now, is there any workaround I can do?

I am looking for anything that can either let me clear the cache before building starts, or customize the build command to a different gradle task, or anything else that may help

Comment: I solved this by changing node and yarn directory to be relative to the project - in .gradle/

This fixes the issue and also caches the installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A part of the problem is the `gradle-node-plugin` is creating symlinks with absolute paths. It should probably be creating relative paths.

In any case, I've opened a [PR on the Gradle buildpack to exclude this dir from the cache](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle/pull/50). Once that's released, this problem should go away.